# On Tradingview, how can I see 2 oscilators on the same window, but different scales?

Tags: trading, tradingview-api, indicator

I'm coding simple pinescript indicators, and in this case I want to combine an ATR and an RSI, both with overlay=false (meaning, they're not over the chart, but in a separate oscillator window).

The issue is that due to the nature of ATR (can go from 0 to thousands, depending on the asset) and RSI (0 to 100), the RSI might not be visible when an asset's ATR is either too low or too high compared to it.

Is there a way around this? Thanks!

I looked for help on google but didn't find any. Also, overlay=true doesn't work as I wanted - it overlays on the chart itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your RSI is between 0 to 100.
You can adapt your ATR to this scale (the value won't be the ATR value anymore BUT you will see the evolution of the ATR)

For this, you must know the max and min value of the ATR on your chart.
Firdt, you need to know the number of bars on your screen, then you will be able to find the Min and the Max of the ATR on your screen.
Once you have the Min and the Max, you have the range of your ATR value and then it is easy to sclae it between 0 to 100.

Here a working code :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="ATR & RSI", shorttitle="ATR & RSI", overlay=false, max_bars_back = 500)

// Find the number of bar on the screen
time_on_chart = (time - chart.left_visible_bar_time)/1000 // time in second
number_of_bar = int(time_on_chart / timeframe.in_seconds()) + 1

// ATR
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=14, minval=1)
smoothing = input.string(title="Smoothing", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
ma_function(source, length) =>
    switch smoothing
        "RMA" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        => ta.wma(source, length)
ATR = ma_function(ta.tr(true), length)

// Find the max value for ATR on screen
Max_Atr = ta.highest(ATR, number_of_bar > 0 ? number_of_bar : 1) 
Min_Atr = ta.lowest(ATR, number_of_bar > 0 ? number_of_bar : 1)


Range_ATR  = Max_Atr - Min_Atr
coef = 100/ Max_Atr

plot(ATR*coef - Min_Atr, title = "ATR", color=color.new(#B71C1C, 0))

// Calcul of thr RSI
ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
//plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```